# html table from random sequence in a for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop, random, html-table

Because I am a music nerd, I've made a little script to generate a random rhythmic pattern:

```
echo "X ";
for ($beats=rand(0,11); $beats>0; $beats--){
  $xo=rand(0,2);
  if ($xo==0){
    echo "x ";
  }
  else {
    echo "- ";
  }
}
```

It gives a random rhythm of up to 12 beats, where 'x' indicates an accented beat, with the first beat always accented. (Example output: X-x-x--)

Now, for looks, I'd like to place this data into an html table. I would like the markup for the example above to be like so:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Beat:</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accent:</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Alas, this is where my programming skill ends. Can anyone offer some code to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Beat:</th>

<?
$times = rand(1,12);
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $times) {
  echo "<th>$i</th>";
  $i++;
}
?>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Accent:</td>
    <td>X</td>

<?
$i = 1;
while ($i <= ($times-1)) {
  if (rand(0,1)) { echo "<td>x</td>";}
  else {echo "<td>-</td>";}
  $i++;
}
?>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is VERY close! At first glance it is lacking the 'lines' of the table, and starts the accents directly under the word 'Beat' with no 'accent' box.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the "Accent" label at the start of the second row - now it should be fine.

Comment: Ziarno, you are a true renaissance man or woman. I shall sing your praises to serialism geeks far and wide!

Answer (score 2):

Just generate the pattern inside a table:

```
<?php
    $numBeats=rand(0,11);
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <?php
        echo "<td>Beat:</td>";
        for ($i=1; $i<=$numBeats+1; $i++){
            echo "<td>" . $i  . "</td>";
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
        echo "<td>Accent:</td>";
        echo "<td>X</td>";
        for ($beats=$numBeats; $beats>0; $beats--){
          $xo=rand(0,2);
          if ($xo==0){
            echo "<td>x</td>";
          }
          else {
            echo "<td>-</td>";
          }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not quite - the "Beat" row also has to have a number of columns to correspond with the generated accent marks. Run the code and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `$beats` is `rand(0,11)` so table can have different number of columns - sometimes 7, sometimes more, sometimes less.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - the number of th tags (the top column) should vary along with the number of beats. So if the bottom column of the table reads "Accents: X--X-" the top should read "Beat:1 2 3 4 5"

... there should be between 1 and 12 columns generated (in addition to the labels 'Accents' and 'beats' on the left.

Comment: This answer always generates 7 columns

Comment: Now it generates a random number of beats.